# How to fix canvas seo limits?

Tags: canvas, seo

I'm a designer who is also a noob developer. I know basic html/css/javascript/python. I for the most part design my sites using the canvas element since I'm really good with vector art and can make kicK ass sites like that. I didn't know that seo crawlers cant really read text in canvas elements very well practically making my site invisible to google. On another thread here someone mentioned that this could be fixed if one were to "programmatically move html elements with the text using CSS". Can someone please explain a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
display: none;
```

This will remove the element from the flow of the page (and from sight) but will still [allow google to index it](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35939/is-hidden-content-display-none-indexed-by-search-engines).

[Display property documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm a bit confused. If I set my canvas element to display none, won't that stop it from being rendered on the page?

Comment: I thought you wanted to hide the text and show the canvas or did I misunderstand.